# Can I override Python list displays?

Tags: python, list, overriding

I'd like to change the behavior of Python's list displays so that instead of producing a `list`, they produce a subclass of `list` that I've written.  (Note: I don't think this is a good idea; I'm doing it for fun, not actual use.)

Here's what I've done:

```
old_list = list

class CallableList(old_list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        old_list.__init__(self)
        for arg in args:
            self.append(arg)
    def __call__(self, start, end=None):
        if end:
            return self[start:end]
        return self[start]

list = CallableList
```

Once that's done, this returns the third element of the list:

```
x = list(1, 2, 3)
print x(2)
```

but this still gives an error:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
print x(2)
```

The error is pretty straightforward:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "list_test.py", line 23, in <module>
    print x(2)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I think there's probably no way of doing this, but I can't find anything that says so definitively.  Any ideas?

Comment: you don't need override the constructer at all because you're not changing the way that the list is constructed, you're just adding a method.

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth: You cannot add methods to types defined in C such as the built-in `list`.

Comment: Isn't `__init__` supposed to return the new object?

Comment: No.  It just initializes it, as the name suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot trivially override the syntactic sugar used for built-in types, since this happens at the compiler level. Always call the constructor explicitly.

Comment: This is true. Also it seems that what you are looking for is list.__getitem__(x): L.__getitem__(x) <==> L[x]

Answer (score 1):

You can't change it from within Python.  Constructs such as list-comprehensions always use the built-in list type, not whatever you've defined the word `list` to in the current namespace.  If you want to change the built-in type, you have to edit the Python source code and recompile.  Assuming you're using the CPython implementation, it lives in [Objects/listobject.c](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/py3k/Objects/listobject.c?view=markup).

Comment: Or you could write your own compiler in Python. Python does provide the facilities to do so.

Answer (score -1):

```
   >>> print(x(2)) # works in 2.7
   3
   >>> type(x)
   <class '__main__.CallableList'>
   >>> y = [1,2,3]
   >>> type(y)
   <type 'list'>
```

so you haven't really redefined type 'list,' you've only changed your namespace so that the type list's list() method now clashes with your type CallableList type. To avoid this,

```
   >>> fred = CallableList
   >>> type(fred)
   <type 'type'>
   >>> x = fred(1,2,3)
   >>> x
   [1, 2, 3]
   >>> print x(2)
   3
   >>>
```